# Optimizing generating an array of pairs from an array without duplicates in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, optimization

I'm generating a big array of pairs from a 1D array, the code has to check and eliminate strictly all duplicates (i.e. if [1,2] exists, then no [2,1] to be produced). For example:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
pairs = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
```

My solution currently takes 60 seconds to generate an array of size N=460 (result will be around `110,000` pairs). The code is below:

```
private function generateAllCombination($scripts)
{
    $combinations = [];
    $pairsIndex = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($scripts) - 1; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($scripts); $j++) {
            // pairs must consist of tuples with distinct values
            if ($i != $j) {
                $pair = array(
                    $scripts[$i],
                    $scripts[$j]
                );

                // only add unique tuples
                $pairTuple = '[' . $i . ',' . $j. ']';
                $pairTupleRev = '[' . $j . ',' . $i . ']';

                if (strpos($pairsIndex, $pairTuple) === false) {
                    $combinations[] = $pair;

                    if ($j > $i) {
                        $pairsIndex .= $pairTupleRev;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $pairsIndex = str_replace($pairTuple, '', $pairsIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $combinations;
}
```

I reckon the checking of duplicates is killing it in the 2D nested loop, but not sure how to optimize it efficiently. Any recommendation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `arr` does not contain duplicates, then you just have to begin the second loop from the next index:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($scripts) - 1; $i++) {
      for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($scripts); $j++) {
            //no need to check, just make a pair
```